# SharePoint 2013 and LYNC

Tags: sharepoint-server, lync

I have following requirements

1. Display user with presence indicator in a sharepoint page and on hover it should display contact card.
2. User should be able to chat or call from sharepoint page.

I have name control dll installed but presence indicator is not working in IE, sometimes blue color is displayed.

Any idea what need to be done?

Comment: Does user have Lync client running? Also please elaborate versions of SP and Lync and IE and possible security hardenings in place for IE.

Comment: yes lync is running ( does user need to login to lync as well ?)  Sharepoint -2013 IE-11 Lync 2010